# How to customize Wordpress Theme before going live

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Yesterday I installed a new theme on Wordpress on my self-hosted website. I am aware of the feature that allows you to preview a theme and have used it to select a new Theme that I want to install.

**Problem**
I do not want to interrupt normal operations of my website, but this new theme requires a lot of customization before it is ready to go. How do I do this?

**My Crappy Solution**
Is the only way to go about it to run a virtual server on my desktop? This seems tedious, not to mention all the errors I usually get when switching to the "real" server when doing this.

**A better way?**
I've been searching on SO as well as the [WordPress](http://en.forums.wordpress.com/forum/themes) Forum for an answer as to how to do this, but have come up short. I would have thought this is a common question. Maybe I'm using the wrong search terms `[themes, customization, before installing]`???

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Poyi's advice is good but if you dont want to set up Wamp/Mamp/Xampp then just create a subdomain on your server, copy the site to that and do your updates. The bonus of this is that the server configurations are of course the same. Password protect the subdomain to ensure it doesnt get crawled.

Comment: There might be a way by using the `get_stylesheet` and `get_template` filter hooks. Hold on a second for me to try it.

Comment: @NikolaIvanovNikolov Thanks for that recommendation! I think this might be the easiest way of going about it. Installing new plug-ins can lead to other problems, which is why I try to limit their use.

Comment: @NikolaIvanovNikolov I'd like to use your answer as the accepted one. Can you put it as a seperate answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, since your question is a pretty good one and probably not a few people are going through the same process when they decide to update their site, I decided to give a try to the `get_stylesheet` and `get_template` filter hooks. It turns out that with a very small plugin, you can easily enforce a specific theme(well in this case any logged-in visitor, but you can change this to use any logic you want) according to a specific rule/s.

Here's the code that you need to put in a file in your plugins directory:

```
<?php 
/*
Plugin Name: Switch Theme
Description: Switches the theme for logged-in visitors, while keeping the current theme for everyone else. !!!NOTE!!! Please back-up your database prior using this plugin - I can't guarantee that it will work with any theme, nor that it won't break your site's set-up - USE AT YOUR OWN RISK(I did a quick test and it seemed to be fine, but haven't done extensive testing).

You don't need to switch to the desired theme before that - you want to keep active the theme that you will display to your visitors - the one that you will see will be used programatically.

Before activating the plugin, change the line that says `private $admin_theme = '';` to `private $admin_theme = 'theme-directory-name';` where "theme-directory-name" is obviously the name of the directory in which the desired theme resides in.
*/

class MyThemeSwitcher {
    private $admin_theme = '';

    function MyThemeSwitcher() {
        add_filter( 'stylesheet', array( &$this, 'get_stylesheet' ) );
        add_filter( 'template', array( &$this, 'get_template' ) );
    }

    function get_stylesheet($stylesheet = '') {
        if ( is_user_logged_in() && $this->admin_theme ) {
            return $this->admin_theme;
        }
        return $stylesheet;
    }

    function get_template( $template ) {
        if ( is_user_logged_in() && $this->admin_theme ) {
            return $this->admin_theme;
        }
        return $template;
    }
}

$theme_switcher = new MyThemeSwitcher();
```

So - first of all **BACKUP YOUR DATABASE!** I tested locally with Twenty Eleven being the default theme and a basic framework theme as my custom theme - the theme options and navigation menus were saved properly.

Then all you need to do is to update the file(change the line that says `private $admin_theme = '';` to `private $admin_theme = 'theme-slug';` where `theme-slug` is the name of the directory in which the theme you want to use is).

Also - you won't be able to change the `Front page` and `Posts page` options, without this affecting the live site, nor will you be able to change the any shared components that both themes use(Site name, Front Page, Posts page, Posts Per Page, etc options, content and so on).

So if you have no clue whether this solution is for you - well, it depends.

If both themes are not relatively complex, then most-likely you should be able to use this hack. If they are though maybe you should do a second installation of your website as others suggested - I think that a second installation in either a sub-domain or a sub-directory would be the best option for you(simply because moving a multisite database is more complex than moving a normal WP database).

Comment: Thanks! I am not that advanced a user so the subdomain install is likely what I will try! Thank you for your extra effort though! +1 and Accept.

Comment: Just like I said, please make a back-up of your database(files back-up won't be needed since the plugin should only be able to cause issues with your db) - so in case anything goes wrong, you can always go back and import your back-up :) Better safe than sorry :)

Comment: Mind that in this case you would be working on the live data! I would not advise to do that for developping a new theme. You should use a copy of your original data. Although this get_stylesheet trick is really interesting (I have used it for mobile theme switching in one of my sites).

Comment: Developing a new theme is totally not advisable using this method. But @excelnova will be just switching to a new theme(one that's already working - he just needs to do the content stuff), so it could do the trick. I've been using it for mobile theme switching as well :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd setup local apache server with a wordpress installed to customize and test a new theme. When you finished customizing it then you can upload the theme to your live site and activate it. If there are settings that you need to set in the dashboard then you probably will have to adjust them again. That's one way to test/customize a theme before putting it live.

Comment: If you have a mac you can use something like MAMP to run a local server with database, all you need to do is install wordpress in the folder and experiment.

Comment: Hi Poyi, thanks for the advice. Can you tell me for certain that there is no way to do it on the "live" site... say in the background???

Comment: Well I stumble upon this post that "might" be what you are looking for. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/edit-and-preview-a-theme-without-it-being-live But it's a pain to edit the theme style within the wordpress dashboard unless your theme already has some sort of style editor.

Comment: I'll read up further on the post you found. You managed to at least find someone with the same question as me. I couldn't get even to that stage :- ) +1

Answer (score 1):

You could create a network (make WordPress multisite with `define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);`, see : http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) and then create one sub-site, then turn it "off" with a Maintenance plugin so it is not accessible to users not logged in as admin, export your posts & data from main blog, import them in sub-blog with WordPress default importer, then apply your new theme to this sub-blog and work on it. When everything satisfies you, apply the theme to the main site and deactivate subsite.